# How debug the error when Microsoft Edge crash with Error code: SIGILL

Tags: progressive-web-apps, microsoft-edge

I'm developing Web App and sometimes i've experienced  in devTools in Microsoft Edge. The page crash with a message Error code: SIGILL

in this case the code that crash the page is in the style CSS part of the index.html page, and the code is:

```
 .circle {
   @supports (cx: 1) {
    transform: translateX(0);
    cx: 17;
  }
 }
```

So my question is .... how i can debug what cause edge to crash without start to remove part of the code i've just written?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to debug CSS code without removing any part of them, you can use the Styles pane in Elements tab of the DevTools. By the way, it seems that your code has some mistakes. It should probably be

```
@supports (cx: 1) {
 .circle {
  transform: translateX(0);
  cx: 17;
  }
}
```

Comment: Of course this is a mistake, but a CSS mistake that crash all edge process, so i'm interesting to debug why the edge process crush by a CSS mistake ....